# How to put a success or error alert inside an options alert?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I have a problem trying to put an alert message after completing the action. The application crashes.

```
@IBAction func deleteAccountAction(_ sender: Any) {
    let userID = prefs.value(forKey: "userId") as! String
    print("user id: \(userID)")
    
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Delete account", message: "Are you sure you want          to delete your account?, This action cannot be reversed.", preferredStyle: .alert)
    
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (action) in
        // ...
    }

    let okayAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (action) in
        RestAPIManager.sharedInstance.deleteAccount(userID: userID){
            (json, error) in
            if(json != JSON.null){
                print(json)
                if(json["success"] == true){
                    //here i want succes alert
                }else{
                   self.errorAlert()
                }
            }else{
               
            }
        }
        
    }
    alert.addAction(okayAction)
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)
    self.present(alert, animated: true)
}

func errorAlert(){
    var dialogMessage = UIAlertController(title: "Error",       message: "Error", preferredStyle: .alert)
    self.present(dialogMessage, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I tried to put an alert message after the action but I can't.

Comment: What problem exactly are you having trying to show the second alert? Show what you tried and explain the issue.

Comment: yes I'm trying show alert success or error when user press ok , I tried but the app crashed

Comment: "the app crashed" Which line made the crash?

Comment: I edited my code, added the line that causes the crash, added a method that showed the error alert but the application crashed

Comment: Which line caused the crash? What is the error message from the crash? Please put those details in your question. But do keep in mind that all UI calls must be made on the main queue and the REST API completion handler is most likely not on the main queue.

Comment: I add to see the edit to understand the line that causes the crashes, and it's `self.errorAlert()`, but I guess then that it's in fact `self.present(dialogMessage, animated: true, completion: nil)` . There should be a error message in console (I guess as my previous fellow), that's a thread issue. but share the console content when it crashes (it's basic debugging skill to read console) and locate exact line causing the crash.

Answer (score 0):

is solved needs to be async.

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.errorAlert()
                    }
```